# Newton's method for approximating square roots

Tags: python, newtons-method

I'm trying to program a function to compute Newton's method. Expect I keep getting an error in my code. 
This is the prompt that I was given to write a code for
[image]

And this is my code that I have written down

```
import math

def newton(x):
   tolerance = 0.000001
   estimate = 1.0
   while True:
        estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
        difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        if difference <= tolerance:
            break
   return estimate

def main():
   while True:
       x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
       if x == '':
           break
       x = float(x)
       print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
       print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))
main()
```

And it seems to be working but I keep getting this error when I run checks on Cengage
[image]

I'm not really sure what it means because my code seems to be running just fine. Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: Can you replace the print statements with this format: ```print("The program's estimate is " + str(newton(x)))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to occur when the input is blank. A potential workaround, assuming you would only want positive numbers as input, would be to set a negative number (or anything else of your choice), like -1 for example, as an exit condition:

```py
x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
if not x:
    break
x = float(x)
```

This should avoid the `EOFError`.

---

#### Edit

If you want to use a blank input (hitting the return line) to break out of the loop, you can try this alternative syntax:

```py
x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
if not x:
    break
x = float(x)
```

The `not x` checks if `x` is blank. It is also more *pythonic* than `x == ""`. Additional methods to detect a blank input are in this post as well: [How do you get Python to detect for no input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226489/how-do-you-get-python-to-detect-for-no-input).

Comment: Now the error read as this Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: 
           Traceback (most recent call last):  
     File "newton.py", line 20, in <module>  
     main()  
  File "newton.py", line 15, in main. 
    x = float(input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: "))  
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that it's due to blank input?

Comment: @kerwei In the test output, when a blank line is entered as input, the program encounters the EOF error. It works fine in other cases

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I ran the script locally on the py36 environment and it seems fine

Comment: @kerwei Same here, I'm running it on the py37 environment and it works, but apparently its not running on Cengage

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer when the input is blank the error reads         `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: @Jianna If you are using the code in my answer, then a blank line does not represent any float number. If you try "-1", then the program should work fine.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer but my assignment requires that I allow the user to break the code using the return key

Comment: @Jianna Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I did mine like this and Cengage accepted it.

```
import math

tolerance = 0.000001
def newton(x):
   estimate = 1.0
   while True:
        estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
        difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        if difference <= tolerance:
            break
   return estimate

def main():
   while True:
       x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
       if x == "":
           break
       x = float(x)
       print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
       print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```